# facebook embedded page on a web site doesn't show

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On our website facebook "plugin page" 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
stop working, it doesn't show anything

when checking in Graph API Explorer
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXXXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "Dg033qmY0r7"
  }
}
```

the command is /GET/page-name

When page-name == 'facebook' its working

When I change app token to "Page Access Token" - its working

Any idea how can I embed facebook page in my web site ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy

Answer (score 0):

using CBroe hint I found that the problem was in the **page** age restriction while I was trying to change the **application** restriction